# How to make clone of contact

Tags: apex

I want to make a clone of records created on object Contact.
I have button in my VF page as follows:

```
    <apex:commandButton action="{!CloneContact}" title="Clone " Value="Clone" />
```

and Apex code:

```
    public pagereference CloneContact(){
            try{
                    Contact objCon = [select Id, LastName from contact where id=: COntactID];
                    Contact objConCopy = objCon.clone(false,false,false,true);
                    insert objConCopy;
            }
            catch(exception e){
                system.debug(e.getmessage());

            }
            return null;
        }
```

when I click on clone button its gives me error as `Duplicate record`

Answer (score 1):

The auto-number fields for the Contact object are UNIQUE. So you should not preserve it in the clone method:

> contact objConCopy = objCon.clone(false,false,false,**false**);

[What the doc said:](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=modifying_standard_auto-number_fields.htm)

> The **unique identifiers** for solutions, cases, and contracts are
>   standard auto-number fields.

Comment: How do I display the clone on new page

Comment: @Ritesh It is not related to the question you asked. Create a new one for that.